Does the automorphism group of a connected manifold of dimension at least $2$ act countably transitively?
Consider the following problem for a fixed index set $I$.
Let $X$ be a topological/smooth manifold that is connected and of dimension $n \geq 2$. Consider the automorphism group $\operatorname{Aut}(X) = \{\varphi: X \to X \mid \varphi \text{ is a homeomorphism/diffeomorphism}\}$. Let $S = \{f: I \to X \mid f \text{ is an injection and } \{f(i) \mid i \in I\} \text{ is closed and discrete}\}$ be the set of all ordered collections indexed by $I$ of distinct points in $X$ which are closed and discrete. Does the automorphism group of $X$ act transitively on $S$, meaning that for any $f, g \in S$ there is $\varphi \in \operatorname{Aut}(X)$ with $\varphi \circ f = g$?
It is well-known that for finite $|I| = m$, the answer is positive. In fact, in this case $S$ is simply the collection of ordered distinct $m$-tuples in $X$, and it is well-known that the automorphism group of $X$ acts transitively on $S$ in this case.
My question is about the case $I = \mathbb{N}$. Of course, in this case, we must require $X$ to be non-compact, otherwise the question would become trivial since no compact topological space can contain an infinite subset that is closed and discrete. Is the answer positive in this case? To say it differently, does the automorphism group of a connected manifold of dimension at least $2$ act countably transitively?

This answer takes place in the topological category. The smooth category is much less tractable for this question, and my answer is not accurate there (see the comments regarding the polar coordinate example).

No, the action is not, in general, countably transitive in the sense you have defined.
For a counterexample in dimension 2, consider $X$ as follows. Start with the $2$-sphere $S^2$. Let $P,Q \in S^2$ be two points. Let $X = S^2 - \{P,Q\}$. Now consider two examples of functions $f,g \in S$ where $I=\mathbb N$:

$f$ is defined so that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) = P$;
$g$ is defined so that $\lim_{n \to \infty} g(2n)=P$ whereas $\lim_{n \to \infty} g(2n-1)=Q$.

Every automorphism of $X=S^2 - \{P,Q\}$ extends canonically to an automorphism of $S^2$, and using this you can see that there is no automorphism taking $f$ to $g$.
To prove this statement, you need Freudenthal's theory of ends. As said in the comments, this takes a lot of work, but here is a very rough sketch. For any compact subset $C \subset X$ you consider the set of (path) connected components $\pi_0(X-C)$. Inclusion of compact sets $C \subset C'$ induces a function $\pi_0(X-C') \to \pi_0(X-C)$. This defines an inverse system of $\pi_0$ sets, indexed by the inclusion lattice of compact subsets of $X$. An end is an element of the inverse limit. The union of $X$ and its ends has a compact topology, it is called the end compactification of $X$, and any automorphism of $X$ extends to an automorphism of its end compactification. If you know this theory, it is an easy computation that when you remove a finite set from a compact manifold, the ends correspond naturally to the removed points, and the end compactification is canonically homeomorphic to the original compact manifold.
For my example of $X=S^2 - \{P,Q\}$, here are the facts you can line up to prove that $P,Q$ "are" the ends, and that any automorphism of $X$ extends to an automorphism of $S^2$:

For any compact $C \subset X$, the set $X-C$ contains one component $U(P;C)$ which has $P$ as a limit point and one component $U(Q;C)$ which has $Q$ as a limit point.
Every other component of $X-C$ has compact closure and so does not contribute to the inverse limit
There exists a larger $C'$ such that $U(P;C') \ne U(Q;C')$.

The $S^2 - \{P,Q\}$ counterexample easily extends to any compact, connected manifold with 2 points removed. More complicated counterexamples can be constructed by removing more complicated closed subsets.
The general idea here is that one has to take into account how the given function $f : I \to X$ accumulates on the ends of $X$, in comparison to how the automorphism extends over the ends.

Right. For instance, OP's question has positive answer if $X$ is 1-ended.

@MoisheKohan Can you elaborate on that?

@LeeMosher Thanks for the answer. "Every automorphism of $X=S^2 - {P,Q}$ extends canonically to an automorphism of $S^2$" Could you give a reference for this? I can't really believe it. For example, what if we consider $S^2 \setminus {P, Q} \cong \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus {0}$ and define the map (in polar coordinates) via $(r, \varphi) \mapsto \left( r, \varphi + \frac{1}{r} \right)$? I believe this does not extend continuously to all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

@Smiley1000: That would require some serious work. In nutshell, you would follow Richards' classification of noncompact surfaces in terms of their ends.

@MoisheKohan Thanks for the pointer. Do I understand it correctly that you're referring to "On the classification of noncompact surfaces" by Ian Richards? Do you have a specific theorem in mind that answers my question positively in the $1$-ended case, or do you have a proof in mind which hasn't yet been written down anywhere?

@Smiley1000: Yes. I do not think it is in the literature, I meant to follow his proof.

Indeed your function $(r,\phi) \mapsto (r,\phi+1/r)$ does extend continuously to all of $\mathbb R^2$, taking the origin to the origin, continuously. It also extends to the one point compactification of $\mathbb R^2$ (which is homemorphic to $S^2$), taking $\infty$ to $\infty$, continuously.

I have added a sketch of how to prove the "extension of automorphism" statement, applying the theory of ends.

The one ended case also follows from end theory, also by direct application of the fact that after putting the missing point back in, the automorphism extends (combined with the fact that the sequence $f : \mathbb N \to X$ must converge to the unique end).

Let me add that your function $(r,\phi) \mapsto (r,\phi+1/r)$ does not extend diffeomorphically. The theory of ends is not well concocted for studying extension of diffeomorphisms, and I added an initial paragraph as a disclaimer in that case.

On the other hand there is a different smooth structure on $\mathbb R^2$  (agreeing with the usual structure on $\mathbb R^2 - {(0,0)}$) such that your function extends smoothly.

@LeeMosher Thank you for elaborating on your initial answer.
